# Why cant I get output from devenv?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a strange problem that I can not figure out.  I have a batch program to compile of bunch of solutions, over 40 in total.  I have included a shortened version that works well.

```
If Not Exist ..\Output MD ..\Output

"B:\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" "..\Stand Alone Project\Enum Builder\EnumBuilder.sln" /build > ..\Output\Build.txt
"C:\IntuitiveDev\Bin\EnumBuilder.exe"
Move Rotair_DynamicEnums.* C:\IntuitiveDev\Bin

"B:\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" "Rotair_Types\Rotair_Types.sln" /build >> ..\Output\Build.txt
"B:\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" "Rotair_IMS_Extensions\Rotair_IMS_Extensions.sln" /build >> ..\Output\Build.txt
"B:\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" "Rotair_GeneralFunctions\Rotair_GeneralFunctions.sln" /build >> ..\Output\Build.txt
```

This produces the following output:

> Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 9.0.21022.8. Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
>   ------ Build started: Project: EnumBuilder, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ EnumBuilder -> C:\IntuitiveDev\Bin\EnumBuilder.exe
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
>
> Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 9.0.21022.8. Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
>   ------ Build started: Project: Rotair_Types, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ Rotair_Types -> C:\IntuitiveDev\Bin\Rotair_Types.dll
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
>
> Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 9.0.21022.8. Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
>   ------ Build started: Project: Rotair_IMS_Extensions, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ Rotair_IMS_Extensions ->
>   C:\IntuitiveDev\Bin\Rotair_IMS_Extensions.dll
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
>
> Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 9.0.21022.8. Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
>   ------ Build started: Project: Rotair_GeneralFunctions, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ Rotair_GeneralFunctions ->
>   C:\IntuitiveDev\Bin\Rotair_GeneralFunctions.dll
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Now I am working on another program to automatically generate forms and a business rules dll.  The problem occurs when I try to compile.  I tried making a process but I do not get any output ([How do I compile a .net solution and get the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708252/how-do-i-compile-a-net-solution-and-get-the-output)).

I made this batch file during testing which does compile the project, but I get no output.  Since no one had a clue as to how to fix this I decided to use a batch file similar to the one that worked.  But this produces no output file.

```
"b:\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "c:\temp\test\XXX12_car.sln"  /build >> C:\temp\Build.txt
```

Stranger still, when I enter this command in a dos window I do not get any output either:

```
"b:\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "c:\temp\test\XXX12_car.sln"  /build
```

The output is essential for me to be able to scan for errors but I am at a loss as to why I get output from one method but not the other.

Comment: Try using the `devenv.com` file found in the visual studio folder, as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13051577/5095502).

Comment: Awesome!!  That was the problem.  Although I still could not get the output using Process.Start, the bat file works!